# First server call is taking more time than subsequent call in Windows Azure cloud application?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I am working on windows azure cloud service. First time when i click on login button it takes 6 to 7 seconds but after sometime when i click on same login button it takes 2 seconds. I am not able to understand why it is happening so though the server side code is same for both processing but subsequent calls are quiet faster than first call ?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"First-hit" delay is very common with ASP.NET applications. There is the overhead of JIT compilation, and various "pools" (database connections, threads, etc) may not be initialized. If you have an ASP.NET Web Forms application, each .aspx page is compiled the first time it is accessed, not when the server starts up. Also the various caching mechanisms (server or client) that make subsequent requests faster are not initialized on that first hit. And on the very first hit, any code in Application_Start will be run, setting up routing tables and doing any other initialization.

There are various things you can do to prevent your users from seeing this delay. The simplest is to write some kind of automated process that hits every page and run it after deploying a new release. There are also modules for IIS that will run code ahead of the Application_Start, when the site is actually deployed. [Search for "ASP.NET warmup"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=asp.net%20warmup) to find those.

You may also experience delays after a period of inactivity, if your ASP.NET App Pool is recycled - this resets a bunch of things and causes start-up code to be run again on the next request. You can ameliorate this effect by setting up something to ping a page on your site frequently so that if the app pool is recycled it is warmed up again automatically, instead of on the next actual user request. Using an uptime monitoring service will work for this, or a Scheduled Task within the Azure ecosystem itself.